# Describe typescript function which returns modified object with keys from array

Tags: typescript

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wVYBDGwBq2ANgJYAmA8gEYBWwC8AvHADwCwAUHHACpyh5kZVHHRQSyAOYAaTtwCSFfiEHC4AbzgBtANJwJvALoB%20AFxwArsgDWyCAHdkcAL5wAZHABK9aGRZiJGUsbO0cAPlkuOAolZk1dfSceE3NFXUMXTjCACjlEsAsYajoGVIpI7mBkbCoiYAAFKAgwYFgSYFQAQSgobABPcx4tQ04ASnMYuEYwjTy6%20CxUCyIYc3i9A2SzODSdDNc45wBuPKqausbm1ph2rp7%20gDoAM2gAUWwEAAts7LAmltgA14oymM3UeW4JCecGyxXoMAefwgMGRfRaD0%202FQFEclwBMD6DwQxCI2QkBSKtHh0jgSPxfVGIPBUW43EWyxgWjp1z6GWY5MKcIYXP%20PMMJxZmSizlGErZwBgFigTnZKyOcAA9BqeGjgHAAOTrRJGba7DIAH2CZGATwkwDI6uc%20v0Ijs8CxqBIkmqtT1KLgBJaBpi%20oewYozqQyzIcCoeok6GwyBuuHtcHsJBgnzgSZzUComd6UD6Ad16c%20JC%20iAg0djeqsWCIqZj-sN2g2SRSOwo6Tglqs1ttyHtjtD2QATABmcfj0acY6cTha3gdGCoRccJBoeASIVMWZRABE1mAfQAjIfzIeAG7ECzAC8VODH0-jy-P29Ee9vp8vvqT98bzvYAAN-E8%20gAfVABAOlQQDP3vAAWQ9ImcDct3QfgfTqMgdFPERmC0fVwLPfUaWI18yINcDJ31EYOE4DD4GHexiimRAsFTQhSEoKkGDJZA9xpM5fVw-CQSXDU4BYti4kk1k-wvK8EIfFD5O4P832U4Cf3U58aPg4DQPktCGI4ZdAz1AA5YBWNodjmWXDSSPfAIpEiJz9NfVyYHEdy9L-ADzDcmQTKAA)

How can I describe type for this function?
inputObject must have all keys from enablePropertiesArray and may have some other keys.
Function must return copy of inputObject, but only with keys from enablePropertiesArray.

```
export const createValidObject = <
  T extends string,
  IO extends { [K in T]?: unknown } & Record<string, unknown>,
  OO = { [K in T]?: IO[K] }
>(
  inputObject: IO,
  enablePropertiesArray: T[]
): OO => {
  let result: { [K in T]?: IO[K] } = {};
  enablePropertiesArray.forEach((property: T) => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(inputObject, property)) {
      result[property] = inputObject[property];
    }
  });
  return result; //Type '{ [K in T]?: IO[K] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'OO'. 'OO' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ [K in T]?: IO[K] | undefined; }'.(2322)
};

// Tests

const inObject = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key_excess": "value4",
}

const enabledKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

const newObj = createValidObject(inObject, enabledKeys) 
// newObj = {
//   "key1": "value1",
//   "key2": "value2",
//   "key3": "value3",
// }

// type NewObj = {
//   "key1": string,
//   "key2": string,
//   "key3": string,
// }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my go.

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-qldqh9Pl9Mm-Jj9QR8wGffcgA)

The main change is making `T` an array instead of a single type. Also, changed the input types in the example to `as const` to make sure type information isn't lost.

```
function createValidObject<IO, T extends readonly (keyof IO)[]>(inputObject: IO, enablePropertiesArray: T): { [K in T[number]]: IO[K] } {
  const result = {} as { [K in T[number]]: IO[K] };
  for (const property of enablePropertiesArray) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(inputObject, property)) {
      result[property] = inputObject[property];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

```
const inObject = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key_excess": "value4",
} as const;

const enabledKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] as const;

const newObj = createValidObject(inObject, enabledKeys);
// const newObj: {
//     key1: "value1";
//     key2: "value2";
//     key3: "value3";
// }
```

Comment: Can I do array "as const" inside createValidObject function? If I must do it everytime when I call this function, then I need fix it many times.

Comment: Unfortunately the `as const` is necessary for at least the `enabledKeys`. Without it TypeScript widens the type to `string[]` instead of `['key1', ...]`, so that isn't enough info to make the types work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right or optimal way to do it but I got your example working with these changes:

```
const createValidObject = <
  T extends string,
  IO extends { [K in T]?: unknown } & Record<string, unknown>,
  OO = { [K in T]?: IO[K] }
>(
  inputObject: IO,
  enablePropertiesArray: T[]
): OO => {

  // 1. Initiate new object with type OO
  let result: OO = {} as OO;
  enablePropertiesArray.forEach((property: T) => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(inputObject, property)) {

      // 2. Assign each matching value as a new object
      Object.assign(result, { [property]: inputObject[property] })
    }
  });
  return result;
});
```