# Typescript function that returns modified object with correct types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

this might sound stupid but I want to know If I can use a function that returns a modified object and display the correct type in return.

The input is as followings

```
{
  enable: { label: "Enable", value: false },
  castShadow: {
           label: "Intensity",
           value: 25,
           condition: currentValue.type === "Circle"}
}
```

As for the return value, I want to modify it to be just like this

```
{enable:true,castShadow:40}
```

To final goal I want to achieve is this one if it is possible

```
  const { ConfigRenderer, enable, castShadow} = useConfig({
        enable: { label: "Enable", value: false },
         castShadow: {
           label: "Intensity",
           value: 25,
           condition: currentValue.type === "Circle"}
  });
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more information? I am unsure how you have derived the valued of `castShadow` in your second code example. Is this just the `value` from the input?

Comment: Value can be boolean, number, or any primitive values that the user might use.
So basically, all properties are modified via UI and were sent back to the function before returning. 

It's really similar to this one but with modified object values
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768468/describe-typescript-function-which-returns-modified-object-with-keys-from-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like this:

```
type ValuesOf<T, P = 'value'> = { 
   [K in keyof T]: P extends (keyof T[K]) ? T[K][P] : never 
};

function useConfig<T>(param: T): ValuesOf<T> {
   // ...
}
```

The `ValuesOf` type is a mapped type that will contain all keys of type `T` but maps them to the type of the property `P` inside type `T` (or to never, if property `P` does not exist on type `T`). In the  code above `P` is defaulted to `'value'` but you could as well use any other property name or even a union of property names.